# ASP.NET - Serving dynamic images from a single URL

Tags: asp.net, session

I am trying to use different background images from session to session. So if users open my website in a different session(e.g. Close and reopen the browser or wait for half an hour), they will see a different background image.

Following is what I am currently doing.

I created a `HttpHandler` class that handles `background.axd`.

First it checks whether there is an entry called `BackgroundIndex` in the `HttpContext.Current.Session`, if not, it randomly chooses a image from the ones that I have, than stores its index into the `Session` object.

Then it compares the index with the value of the `If-None-Match` header, if they match, simply return a response with `304 Not Modified`.

If not match, or there isn't a 'If-None-Match' header in the request, it writes the content of the image file to the response and return it with `ETag` header set to the index of the image.

At last, I set the background image of my website to `background.axd` in my CSS file.

The problem is, it works correctly, but not efficiently.

The image file for current session can be loaded from cache. But if the session changes, the browser will have to download the image from my server even if it has been downloaded before.

Also, the browser has to make additional request to check if the image in cache has been out of date.

Is there a better solution for this?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why not just change the background via CSS class? You can make the area you use the background on, to have a CSS class which you change on your server, depending on the session details. Then that class dictates which background image to use. That way, you can leave the user's browser to decide if it need to request that image or it has it on its cache.

Comment: @FrankFajardo But if I have 20 images, I need to create 20 CSS classes? I don't have much knowledge about CSS, point it out please if I said is something wrong.

Comment: Yes. You can learn CSS background-images [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp). Most web controls have CssClass properties so you can change that on the server. Or you can wrap your content in a `<div id="myDiv" class="..." runat="server">` and add the class on that div using `myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "className")`, or update via `myDiv.Attributes["class"] = "className"`.